# wp-admin/includes/class-pclzip.php error set_magic_quotes_runtime() removed since PHP 7.0

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7, phpcs

I've checked my code compatibility with PHP 7 using PHP Code Sniffer, PHPCompatibility and I got the error bellow.

```
    [1mFILE: ...php7/wp-admin/includes/class-pclzip.php[0m
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[1mFOUND 2 ERRORS AFFECTING 2 LINES[0m
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 5345 | [31mERROR[0m | [1mFunction set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated since
      |       | PHP 5.3 and removed since PHP 7.0[0m
      |       | (PHPCompatibility.PHP.DeprecatedFunctions.set_magic_quotes_runtimeDeprecatedRemoved)
 5376 | [31mERROR[0m | [1mFunction set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated since
      |       | PHP 5.3 and removed since PHP 7.0[0m
      |       | (PHPCompatibility.PHP.DeprecatedFunctions.set_magic_quotes_runtimeDeprecatedRemoved)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

class-pclzip.php comes with Wordpress default installation. I would like to know if anyone was found an issue with this running on PHP 7. There was a [fix](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18549) for this but I wanted to double check anyway once this error is still appearing on my code sniffer log .

Comment: Presumably you were running PHP Compatibility against an earlier pre PHP7 version of WordPress that did not have the fix implemented, otherwise you shouldn't have seen this error...?